# Should any liquid be swallowed, seek medical advice immediately

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

How is this sentence imperative or whatever? It looks like interrogative in the first half then imperative in the second half.

Comment: see [***should***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/should) - 4. used to express a future condition"   ⇒ *if I should die tomorrow, if you should be late*"

Answer (score 2):

That "should" in the first half is **not** interrogative at all.

The first half is conditional - similar to an "if clause": ***if*** any of the liquid is swallowed, it results in something else.

The second half is an imperative that takes effect ***if*** the liquid gets swallowed.